# Interface implementation hiding method

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I need advice on interfaces. I have a class called Unit which can attack other units. The attack can be air or ground. I need single method to achieve attacking called `attack()`. Some units can only attack ground units, some air units or both.

This is what I've come up so far:

```
public interface Attack() {
    public void attack(SCObject object);
}

public interface GroundAttack() extends Attack {
    public void groundAttack(SCObject object);
}

public interface AirAttack() extends Attack {
    public void airAttack(SCObject object);
}
```

I have can have different units:

```
Unit extends SCObject implements GroundAttack {
}

Unit extends SCObject implements AirAttack {
}

Unit extends SCObject implements AirAttack, GroundAttack {
}
```

The problem is this implementation will reveal the two ground and air options whereas I only want `attack()` method to be visible.
Can you propose solution or does this seem ok to you?

Comment: Are your restrictions (air vs ground) static (i.e. resolvable at compile time) or dynamic (resolvable at runtime) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use

```
public interface Attack {
    public boolean canAttack(SCObject object);
    public void attack(SCObject object);
}
```

I don't see a reason to have a specific ground or air attack method given you didn't want to expose this behaviour.

Comment: Visitor pattern might be useful here as well.

Comment: @BrianAgnew Thank you for fixing the typos.

Comment: If you don't implement any interface unit cannot attack. And unit that doesn't implement AirAttack can't attack flying units.

Comment: @locke Where does this requirement come from? Is it something you have to live with or something you can fix?

Comment: @PeterLawrey it is coming from my head and I want to fix it.

Comment: @locke in that case make it that any Unit which implements Attack and returns `true` to `canAttack()` can attack. If you don't really need to know this you could just call `attackIfYouCan()` blindly and have it do nothing if it has no options. Each unit can see how far away the other unit is, (on the ground or in the air) to see if it is in range. A ground unit cannot attack a ground unit out of range, and possibly a unit in the air is always out of range unless it is on the ground.

Comment: Thanks for the poitners. Visitor pattern and in interface with two methods attack and canAttack sorted this for me.

Answer (score 3):

I think the [visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) or [double-dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) pattern *may* apply here, given that the ability to attack depends on interactions between the attacker and victim.

Some form of invocation in which the attacker `attacks()`, and passes *itself* as an argument will allow the victim to determine the validity of the attack. Note that this could allow you to change the attackability at runtime (e.g. can a 'ground' unit take to the air?)